# Is this iso flare corrrect?

Tags: brakes, brake-lines

I am attempting to implement an iso flare on a 1/4' (6m) line. As this is the line that supplies both rear brakes I want to be sure it is done correctly, below is a link to photos of all 4 sides and an overhead view.

[image]

.
[More images here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMM3rYXEABfyaqZAy2eRRMu04DGhYhT1i74sLrIKKgNeOVVFHYIA3fnL4WChlCOgA?key=UjF6YnhkNlFZaDNMWU5wZndMX0hIaFlsZjVYbXd3)

My primary concern is that there appears to be an imperfection on one of the sides where the 'bubble' meets the opening at the end of the line.

Is this a correct ISO flare?

Comment: If you are not sure what you are doing then get it done by a professional. Brake safety is for the safety of others as well as yourself so doing it “cheap” is not an option.

Comment: While I appreciate your concern this line is for a project car whos perpos is for me to learn as I go. So having a shop do this for me would defeat the purpose of the build for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a little over pressed to me, bubble should be smooth curve all the way around, looks like it has a ledge on one side as you stated.

Try again this time cut the tube straight across and use a small file to round the outer edge of the tube before forming it, a little lube on the die also. I takes practice.

Also not all flare tools are equal, use the highest quality one you can afford. I have found cheap ones do a poor job.

Comment: Through some experementation I managed to get a good flare by backing the line out of the bar slightly. So this is indeed the correct answer.

As well I did buy a cheap tool, so ill be upgrading for my next project

Comment: Best brake line I ever used, bends and forms easy, this is just the one I used, but amazon sells similar now for much cheaper>>>>https://www.autozone.com/brakes-and-traction-control/brake-line/ags-nicopp-nickel-copper-brake-line-tubing-coil/580013_0